# How to remap "quit application" to Command+ESC system wide?

Tags: macos, keyboard, settings, keybindings, applications

As of now it's set to <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>Q</kbd> everywhere which is very unintuitive and being next to <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>W</kbd>, which I use a lot, it's very annoying too.

<kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>Esc</kbd> doesn't do anything (on my laptop at least) and I think it makes sense to remap the quit action to it. I think I can do it one by one - one app at a time. But is there a way I can change it for all the apps at once - from one setting, or using some tool?

And I would like <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>Q</kbd> to do something else or nothing at all.

Answer (score 1):

Well this sure turned out to be a question that seemed simple, but snowballed into a hassle to solve.

I'm going to kind of start from the beginning:

Turns out disabling <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> natively is only possible if you are ok with actually just replacing it with another function. Just outright disabling it is a no go... But, some third party apps can overwrite it. I'll get to that later. Also, as simple of an idea as it seems, you can't set a new shortcut for "Quit" through the native keyboard shortcut editor thing, because that relies on the full menu item name and wouldn't you guess it, it's most often: "Quit {application name}" so it's impossible to target all apps with that single shortcut.

Then I thought... Alright, how aboutAutomator Service. I could use an apple script to close applications with that... Well, you can't set the shortcut <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd> for Automator Services apparently, but you can set that shortcut globally in some third party apps, which is the way I ended up doing it all.

**Solution:**

So I tried to find the cheapest third party app I have that can do all that we want to happen, enter [BetterTouchTool](https://www.boastr.net/).

<sub><sup>[Karabiner](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/) should be able to do this for free, but a version that works in Sierra and later is under a rewrite,
 not sure if it currently has the power to do it...</sup></sub>

1. In BTT, I made a new global keyboard shortcut <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> and defined no action for it, essentially disabling it.
2. Then I made another shortcut: <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd> with the predefined action `Run Apple Script in background`:

---

```
tell application "System Events"
    set frontmostApp to name of the first application process whose frontmost is true
end tell
tell application frontmostApp to quit
```

You should know that this applescript should work in most applications, but not all of them. I'm not aware of a bulletproof way to do it.

<sup><sub>This shortcut could just be "Trigger other keyboard shortcut: Cmd+Q", but since we disabled that shortcut, that is no longer an option.</sub></sup>

[image]

That's it.